# Get Image from FTP without saving it locally and print it

Tags: php

I am trying to get Image from FTP server and print it afterwards without saving it locally. My problem is, that the image is in some kind of crypted form probably, or in Binary, honestly I have no idea.

This is a code I do have so far:

```
public function getImagePreview($imageName){
  if(ftp_get($this->connection, "php://output", "web/media/images/".$imageName, FTP_BINARY)){
    $data = ob_get_contents();
    $dataSize =  ob_get_length();
    ob_end_clean();
    return array('data' => $data, 'size' => $dataSize);
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

It's a method inside one object that I am calling from a file and here is a the code I am trying to show the image.

This line is for getting the Image (calling the function above), but it's a different PHP file! This is a view file.

```
require_once "../objects/ftpm.php";
$ftpM = new FTPManager();
$image = $ftpM->getImagePreview($imageName);
```

And here I am trying to print the image.

```
<span> Preview </span>
<img class="materialboxed" width="650" src="<?php echo $image["data"]; ?>"/>
```

But it actually shows tons of this code (I showed only a few lines as an example, since it's so extremely long):

> ����JFIFdd��Duckyd��Adobed������Ul���    u!"1A2# QBa$3Rq�b�%C���&4r ��5'�S6��DTsEF7Gc(UVW�����d�t��e�����)8f�u*9:HIJXYZghijvwxyz�������������������������������������������������������m!1"AQ2aqB�#�R�b3 �$��Cr��4%�ScD�&5T6Ed' s��Ft����UeuV7��������)��������������(GWf8v��������gw��������HXhx��������9IYiy��������*:JZjz����������?��ߺ�^��׽��u�~��{ߺ�^��׽��u�~��{ߺ�^��׽��u�~��{ߺ�^��׽��u�~��{ߺ�^��׽��u�~��{ߺ�^��׽��u�~��{ߺ�^��׽��u�~��{ߺ�^��׽��u�~��{ߺ�^��׽��u�~��{ߺ�^��׽��u�~��{ߺ�^��׈�ߺ�P*q�uHRh����<��fV��(�u ���nG�u�Tb��?��1g�,�Q�9g��6GԼ����ӌ��X J��G���4�abk>�׺F�b1��ޖ��x%w>$y�{�M]^���UZ�Kma��{��^*�><���VX�y����4���V�p?�׺GɆ��^3L�gO4_s5���B���7�[���u�|B���&a�`��l�nm��׺s��E-%�ԽEi�-<2��2�b5����-� {�^�=}3:�WQhjVL�[PY��Y�bC�JX����y����i*�Ӗ�2�t�GD�e Dͨ$r�K�r\X}8�^�W�� jI�"��,ji|0$S�U��J��.�R�H��}��t���-fBi�.6����$��b�+{\���~��a�����%:����Y�$���9U�}���Ҷ�YVq�Z�ɞ9�xPL嘆q�r��p-��{�,\k5��3�KG�!��Le�Ą����׺�b�/S 4�ߠ�#i�d�ԓoΛ{�^�g���>@�9$8��:CH�jF$��*)��u�Q�}��t#����F���2:0ee?B� ~��r��׽��u�~��{ߺ�^��׽��u�~��{ߺ�^��׽��u�~��{ߺ�^��׽��u�~��{ߺ�^ c�>�׺Bg6.�ԤoGY&�ii�B��RD��f-� ?�}��t϶Z�-F��;kI�j����7��\�ԅmc�C��׺?B�K)"�a��a��u�r �h�r��,�,�_+k*�O��{�^���MU5\��4�G��+ Y�+1C�������{���t��]K�k�X��L�e(�uCq~��$1{*��_���_S�����䶩N���>���׺VIG�����L�J���Sn8���{��L��w�'��2��hb���2<�8b��rH7~m��{��^K�f�/�䤍i*8Y����#��ʗck)��>�׺a�9s9�Zq9ZX�Q���o!���j &�U��I��6ߺ�K��0�S�]T�jii֊/�>o=\�-eBO�_�{�=NRz$�t����5%|�J)�����J,����X�#�����{�/%OY����� rX(Q�b=��t��N�I;F�Lg���6�@��e]Ib����/��{��E�Ʀ@�1hI"G���44�T�A��������׺k�����(��\R�Z2Y������>�o��{�^�7SUG)ED2���&���F�l�^_�z�U��׺*j�)�h���`��2����#��� e1�Z����=��t1�I�|5-VJ�9ni%�Ti$Q��X��UTF����~~��׺Y���WӭM$�OM��&���c��0������~��4U*;N�^$E{8

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ftpM = new FTPManager();
$image = $ftpM->getImagePreview($imageName);
$type = 'jpeg'; // file type here
header("content-type: image/{$type}");
echo $image['data'];
```

Comment: You can't put a different header in the middle of an HTML document.

Comment: Well Firefox responded to me while I was trying to load the page, "Image cannot be loaded because it contains errors". And it looks like it tried to open the whole PHP page as an Image file. Chrome did the same thing.

Comment: @Quentin I placed it in header of the page.

Comment: @Quentin I don't know if there is another way of displaying stream directly into the image source without creating the file. The only solution can be is display the image with content type header.

Comment: @JanKočvara — But the page is an HTML document. Claiming the entire page is a JPEG isn't going to help.

Comment: @skndrkhtr5 — There is, see the duplicate question.

Comment: Unfortunately even with base64_decoding or encoding nothing changes. It still returns the same thing.

Comment: @Quentin oh yes we can do with data:base64 as well, sorry my bad

Comment: But still, even if I go with this it's not working:
  <?php
                          $img64 = base64_encode($bannerImg["data"]);
                          ?>
                          <img class="materialboxed" width="650" src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo $img64;?>"/>

Comment: @JanKočvara did my solution work for you?

Comment: @skndrkhtr5 no, it did not. Sorry.

Comment: The above duplicate solution is working for me. check here https://ibb.co/8YH69yJ .

Comment: You should add some explanation to your code - what does it do, and why does it solve the given question?